# Visual Studio Installer Missing option value: InstallPath - Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2019, corrupt

I have the visual studio 2019 enterprise edition (VS 2019 16.1.4) installed with valid license (Visual Studio Subscription) and it was working good.

All of sudden, when I try to open a project or any file that is part of the project, I am getting the following error.

[image]

So I tried to uninstall using the Visual Studio Uninstaller, when I selected uninstaller, it got updated automatically and when I open uninstaller now, it says

[image]

When I click Ok, it says You haven't installed anything yet and it only has the option to install VS 2019 16.2.0.

Even if I try to install VS 2019 16.2.0 , I see the error

> "Visual Studio cannot be installed to a nonempty directory 'C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise'."

Kindly help me resolve the error.

**Update**

```
=====================
12-08-2019 06:31:09 PM
Recoverable
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration.ISetupConfiguration.GetInstanceForCurrentProcess()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<IsPrereleaseAsync>d__44.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<IsPreviewSDKInUseAsync>d__43.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<CheckCompatibilityAsync>d__47.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<<InitializeAsync>b__40_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectMultiThreadedService.<>c__DisplayClass32_1.<<Fork>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.CommonProjectSystemTools.Rethrow(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectErrorReporting.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<SubmitErrorReport>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ExceptionFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Guard>g__action|0()
   at GuardMethodClass.GuardMethod(Func`1 , Func`2 , Func`2 )
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070490): Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration.ISetupConfiguration.GetInstanceForCurrentProcess()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<IsPrereleaseAsync>d__44.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<IsPreviewSDKInUseAsync>d__43.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<CheckCompatibilityAsync>d__47.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.DotNetCoreProjectCompatibilityDetector.<<InitializeAsync>b__40_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectMultiThreadedService.<>c__DisplayClass32_1.<<Fork>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.CommonProjectSystemTools.Rethrow(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ProjectErrorReporting.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<SubmitErrorReport>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.ExceptionFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Guard>g__action|0()
   at GuardMethodClass.GuardMethod(Func`1 , Func`2 , Func`2 )<---

===================
```

I started to face this issue very frequently(twice a week) and the only solution was to reinstall every time. So downgraded VS to 2017 for now.

Comment: I started experiencing the same right after installing .NET Core SDK 3.0.100-preview6-012264 - I have the strong feeling something got corrupted after that, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't have .NET Core SDK 3.x installed on my machine but I've the same error.

Answer (score 2):

To uninstall the VS 2019, please follow the steps as below to clean up the installed VS and re-install it:

•   See if you have this file on your machine: "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe"

•   If so, please launch it from an admin command prompt with a -full param:
InstallCleanup.exe -full

•   If not, please manually delete the "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer” folder

•   Relaunch the newly downloaded vs_enterprise.exe (or vs_professional.exe or vs_community.exe…)

•   Allow the first step to install the installer

•   Once the installer comes up and you can see workload choices (.net desktop and the like), close it

•   Go launch the same InstallCleanup.exe to clean up old build of VS

•   Then re-run the VS installer to install

Please then let us know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. To escape the above mentioned error, What I did is I manually deleted the files under the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise" and I installed the latest VS16.2.x but now, in "Programs and Features" I see 2 versions of Visual Studio 16.2.x and 16.1.x with respective installation date.

Comment: It seems the VS 2019 16.2 successfully install, right? Just the Programs and Features display 16.1 and 16.2 two instances, have you tried to reboot the computer after the VS installation? If not, please have a try with it.

Comment: Yes, I am able to use VS 2019 16.2. I did restart multiple times but still the Programs and Features show two instances of installation.

Comment: If you right click the VS 16.1.x and choose 'Uninstall', it will popups the installer and requires you to confirm uninstall the VS 2019 enterprise or not? I suppose the previous failed uninstall not completely clean the record and caused this display issues.

Comment: I was not able to uninstall VS 16.1.x when I try to change or uninstall it, it displays the second error image. Kindly look into the update. All of sudden, I am receiving that error message while loading a project.

Comment: Some how the installer gets updated to latest version and when we try to uninstall/change existing version, it results in the error mentioned in question "update". if I continue with the error by ignoring it, it results in the original error mentioned in the question. :(